# Jmeter variables

Tags: jmeter, global-variables

Подскажите, пожалуйста, с помощью чего можно реализовать такое: ( Есть сайты и у каждого есть id, как сделать так, что бы в udv можно было писать название сайта и автоматически подтягивался id который равен названию сайта) что бы id передавался в переменную в зависимости от названия сайта

Answer (score 0):

Пары "имя_сайта=id" можно добавить в файл *user.properties* (лежит в папке "bin" инсталляции JMeter)

```
site1=foo
site2=bar
```

Значения из файла можно прочитать с помощью функции [__P()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И затем обращаться к значениям используя обычный синтаксис [переменных JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html):

```
${site1_id}
${site2_id}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Более того, значения `site1`, `site2` и вообще любых [JMeter Properties](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html) можно переопределять "на лету" при помощи [параметра `-J`](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override), если вы запустите JMeter следующим образом:

```
jmeter -Jsite1=baz
```

значение переменной `${site1_id}` будет `baz`

Более подробная информация: [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization/)

Comment: Спасибо большое!